# What is the best way to work with XML?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm newbie in iPhone development and I have a question.
What is best way to work with XML(or another structured format, it is not important for me, I want to store my structured data on the disk)? I want to read and write.
UPDATE: I would like to use standart libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirements and the complexity of the data which method is most appropriate.

For simple and small structures you can use **property lists** for storing (i.e. use NSDictionary's `writeToFile:atomically:`- and `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile`-methods).

If you have complex structures and large amounts of data you may want to look at **core data**.

For XML parsing there are different libraries:
Read this to find out what is most suitable for you: http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project

Comment: Ok, thx, I decided to read XML by NSXMLParser, than write XML by NSDictionary. But I have a problem: i have a ios sdk 3.2, and there is no NSXMLParserDelegate! What can I do? How can I work with NSXMLParser without this protocol?